# Navigating back to your app from Maps app

Tags: ios, navigation, maps, mapkit

I use this code snippet to launch `Maps` iOS native app from mine to show a route:

```
[MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:@[[MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation], mapItemEnd]
                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
```

and my app is correctly moved to background and `Maps` launched. However, it looks like if I want to go back to my app, I have to press the device's button and launch it again from the menu. Is there any way to navigate back to my app directly from `Maps`?

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no way to do this.